# Rust refrence to Box causing lifetime issues

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to build a little physics system in rust just to help me learn rust.

I am trying to set up the architecture the following way:

- `Solver` has a vector of `Bodies`.
- `Body` has a vector of `Particles` and a vector of `Sticks`.
- `Stick` (these are constraints between `Particles`) has references to `Particles`.

The code for these are here: https://github.com/bit-shift-io/rust-verlet/tree/main/src/v2

Now I am trying to assemble these parts in this file: https://github.com/bit-shift-io/rust-verlet/blob/main/src/scenes/car/car_scene.rs

On line 45 of the above file, I get the error:

```
cannot borrow `body` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
mutable borrow occurs hererustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
car_scene.rs(38, 27): immutable borrow occurs here
car_scene.rs(7, 6): lifetime `'a` defined here
car_scene.rs(57, 9): returning this value requires that `body.particles` is borrowed for `'a`
```

I *think* what is happening is that I am borrowing from `body.particles` and passing this `Box` reference to a `Stick` which gets added to the same `Body` as `body.particles`, and so is causing some circular lifetime.

What I was hoping to achieve was that the life time of `Stick` would just depend on the `Particle` lifetime, with the `Body` having ownership of its particles and sticks. i.e. when a `Body` is destroyed, its particles and sticks are also cleaned up at that stage.

Yet rust has forced me to have the `Stick` lifetime applied to the `Body`, then on the `Solver` also!

How should I make this work?

Comment: Holding at the same time values and references to them in a structure forming a tree gives issues similar to what is described [here](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/) for example. Maybe should you store all particles and all sticks in two vectors and reference them with indices instead of real references (as in an [ECS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system)).

Comment: The alternative would be to give up the strict control of ownership, as it is implicitly done in many reference-based languages, by explicitly using [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) and [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html). In such a situation, as long as at least one `Rc` exists, the referenced data still exists, and `RefCell` provides *interior mutability* in order to perform mutations when needed, even when many references exist.